# Is this graph measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I have a problem with a proof: I need to prove that $\Gamma=\lbrace(x,y)| f(x)=y\rbrace $ is measurable, where $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a measurable function from a metric space $X$  with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra into $(Y,\mathcal{F})$ that is a measurable space with $\mathcal{F}$ countable generated and that contains singleton.

I'm reading a proof where they first find a countable algebra of sets $\mathscr{U}$ that generates $\mathcal{F}$, then they show that for every $y\in Y$
$$ \lbrace y\rbrace=\bigcap_{B\in\mathscr{U},y\in B}\ B. $$
By this they conclude that
$$\Gamma=\bigcap_{B\in\mathscr{U}}\left\lbrace (x,y)\mid x\in f^{-1}(B),y\in B \right\rbrace $$
is measurable, but the right-hand side it's empty and this equality seems to me not true.

There is a good way to write the graph that ensure me measurability?

Comment: Why do you think the right side is empty?

Comment: $\mathscr{U}$ is an algebra of sets, it has empty set for example and in general $B\in \mathscr{U} $ couldn't have any point that is in image of $f$.

Comment: Empty set will not contain $y.$ For your problem, you have a fixed $y\in Y$ and you are looking at the set $B\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $y\in B.$

Comment: But in the last equality $y$ is not fixed, if it were fixed there we couldn't have equality with graph $\Gamma$.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: It's hard to answer in place of author. May be he/she mean that $y$ from first equality kept fixed for second. Can you share your source?

Comment: A small fix: $$\Gamma = \bigcap_{B \in \mathscr{U}} \Bigl(\bigl(f^{-1}(B) \times B\bigr) \cup \bigl(f^{-1}(Y\setminus B) \times (Y\setminus B)\bigr)\Bigr)\,.$$

Comment: @zkutch at the end of page 2 in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B00coOUqVAAHUWY0ZDlpRlppUFk/view

Comment: Just an ordinary mistake, the correct version is above. By the way, the letter that looks like a funny 'U' is in fact an uppercase Fraktur 'A', `\mathfrak{A}` gives $\mathfrak{A}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for all! Now everything works!